# c# - outputting a value of infinity

Tags: c#, math, double, nan, infinite

I have part of the calculation that is modified to explain what issue I'm having. I'm converting a working Java code into a c# application.

A double variable is declared doing the following calculation and the following input values being passed along for example:

```
double input1 = 45
double input2 = 42
double input3 = 1

double a = (input1 - input2 * Math.Pow(input3, 2.0)) / (1 - Math.Pow(input3, 2.0));
```

This outputs as an Infinite in c# but Java shows the value. With infinite being outputted, the other calculations below are affected.

```
double b = input1 + input2 - 2 * a (becomes -Infinite)
double c = b + a (gives you NaN)
```

a,b, and c are outputted into individual text boxes and each either show as Infinite or NaN.

```
Textbox1.Text = a.ToString("F") (Infinite)
Textbox2.Text = b.ToString("F") (-Infinite)
Textbox3.Text = c.ToString("F") (NaN)
```

I know that this is due to IEEE standards, but is there actually a way that variable ***a*** shows the value instead of showing infinite so that it doesn't affect the calculations or output the results into a text box in 2 decimal places?

Comment: "variable a shows the value" What value do you expect a to have instead of `Infinity`?

Comment: "but Java shows the value" what value outputs for the above calculation in Java ?

Comment: Obviously `1 - Math.Pow(input3, 2.0)` return 0, because `1 ^ 2 = 1`, which causes a `NullDevisionException`. I doubt that java will ignore this and give you a value.

Comment: C# is correct here, and if Java is giving you a different answer, there's something far wrong with it. I think it more likely that you mistranslated the code. (@HimBromBeere Division by zero for a double does NOT give an exception - it gives the infinity result)

Comment: Any value other than 1, it outputs fine. HimBromBeere was right. I went to double check this on the scientific calculator and it's diving by 0. So there might be a bug in the calculation I was given. But instead of showing a divide by 0 exception, it probably attempted to open a portal to the gates of hell.

Interesting as this was my first time encountering this. I was expecting an exception to be thrown instead and couldn't find anything on google on finding out what the numeric value is it's trying to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is returning a value 0 for the divide part which results into infinity value. which is true here there is nothing wrong in the code. You need to check the calculation.

```
        double input1 = 45;
        double input2 = 42;
        double input3 = 1;

        double a = (input1 - input2 * Math.Pow(input3, 2.0))
            / (1 - Math.Pow(input3, 2.0));

        Console.WriteLine((input1 - input2 * Math.Pow(input3, 2.0)));
        Console.WriteLine((1 - Math.Pow(input3, 2.0)));
        Console.WriteLine(a);
```

check the output on console.

Comment: When I looked more into it, it was in fact diving the value by 0. It was my first time coming across this issue as I was expecting a divided by 0 exception and I didn't know doubles were capable of outputting 'infinite' at that time. The issue with the calculation seems to only happen when 1 is passed into input3

Comment: yes, that was the only case here....

Answer (score 0):

I pasted into a Java test program the code you posted for calculating `a`, and made minimal changes to turn it into compilable Java. I added `;` to the first three declarations, and changed `Math.Pow` to `Math.pow`:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input1 = 45;
    double input2 = 42;
    double input3 = 1;

    double a = (input1 - input2 * Math.pow(input3, 2.0))
        / (1 - Math.pow(input3, 2.0));
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

The program prints, as expected, "Infinity".

If your Java program is getting something different, there is some error in how you are converting it to C#.